# Difference between list and list* in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

While reading:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html

I came across `list*`

Like list, but the last argument is used as the tail of the result, instead of the final element. The result is a list only if the last argument is a list.

What does the: "the last argument is used as the tail of the result, instead of the final element" mean? I thought lists always end with the empty list: `'()`

And if: "The result is a list only if the last argument is a list" then what else is it? i thought everything in scheme is a list.

Comment: Surely this question is a duplicate - it must come up all the time. But it's so hard to search for `list*` that I can't find one. Maybe a Scheme expert remembers it coming up before?

Comment: tried finding it but only this question comes up. which is btw amazing how fast it got indexed.

Comment: "_I thought lists always end with the empty list_" -- the tail of a list is just another list, which ends with `'()`. If you `cons` some object onto the front of that tail, you still have a list, which still ends with `'()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might make more sense to think of `list*` not as a variation on `list`, but as a variation on `cons`.

```
> (cons 1 (list 2 3 4))
(list 1 2 3 4)
> (list* 1 (list 2 3 4))
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

On 2 arguments, `(list* fst rst)` produces the same thing as `(cons fst rst)`.

When there are more arguments, `list*` adds all of them like a multi-argument version of `cons`.

```
> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (list 4 5))))
(list 1 2 3 4 5)
> (list* 1 2 3 (list 4 5))
(list 1 2 3 4 5)
```

And just like `cons` doesn't produce a proper-list if you pass something else as the "rest", `list*` will do the same.

```
> (equal? (cons 1 2) (list* 1 2))
#true
> (equal? (cons 1 (cons 2 3)) (list* 1 2 3))
#true
```

These things are conses, but they are not proper lists.

But the most common uses of `list*` should use a proper list as the last argument. If you're looking for a relationship to `list`, then

```
> (list* 1 2 3 4 '())
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

Using `list*` with `'()` as the last argument will be equivalent to `list` without that.

Comment: what are some use cases for list*?

Comment: whats list* better at than the other solutions?

Comment: list* does not work like append, but there is a relation. `(list* a b c ... d)` is the same as `(append (list a b c ...) d)`

Comment: @X10D -- there really is no "better"; it does what it does, and you use it if that is what you need. It is good for describing how `apply` handles its arguments.

Comment: @AlexKnauth -- an example I don't see in your answer, but which might help OP understand "_the last argument is used as the tail of the result, instead of the final element_": `(list 1 2 3 '(4 5 6))`  -->  `'(1 2 3 (4 5 6))`, but `(list* 1 2 3 '(4 5 6))`  -->  `'(1 2 3 4 5 6)`.

Comment: @X10D I saw that you asked a lot of questions and rarely accepted an answer. Would you mind going through all your questions and accept satisfying answers? This answer by Alex Knauth, for instance, seems to me like a perfect answer to your question. It should really be accepted.